# How to use extracted data from factor analysis in subsequent 2x2 factorial design?

Tags: factor-analysis, ancova, manova

I’m conducting a 2x2 between subjects factorial design for my dissertation.

**IV’s**:

1. advertising appeal (two levels: rational appeal vs. emotional appeal)
2. media type (two levels: TV vs. Internet).

**DV**:

cognitive (thinking) and affective (emotional) customer response

**Covariates**:

1. subjects’ product knowledge
2. involvement with the product
3. yearly spending on high-involvement products
4. general attitudes toward the advertisement
5. general attitude toward the brand.

**Hypotheses**:

1. A combination of different advertising media and appeals (TV/emotional, TV/rational, Internet/emotional, Internet/rational) differently affect consumers' cognitive and emotional responses.
2. Rational Internet ad for high-involvement product is more effective in generating cognitive response compared to rational TV ad for the same category of product.
3. Emotional TV ad for high-involvement product is more effective in generating affective response compared to emotional Internet ad for the same category of product.

Factor analyzed data that has been collected from four treatment conditions (TV / emotional, TV / rational, Internet / emotional, Internet / rational) need to be used in further causal analysis to find out interaction effects (or testing hypothesis 2 and 3).

**Question**:

How can the extracted factors (4 emotional and 4 cognitive) be used in 2x2 MANCOVA analysis?